# Hiding keyboard top addon in react native ios

Tags: reactjs, react-native

[image]In IOS there is a top bar over the keyboard sometimes eg. When the input is focused and the type of input is "tel", it would allow you to paste the phone number with one click or if there is something in sms message. I need to disable it on just one screen. How can I do this? My problem is that on this screen I have a set of inputs for a single code number with max length 1 and when I try to intercept this on press I get only one digit consoled so I cannot do anything with it. Perhaps there is an event of sorts that would allow me to read the full input even with the length limitation set on the input? Or if not that I would need to hide it. I use react-native-avoid-softinput to handle avoiding keyboard if that makes any difference.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **KeyboardAvoidingView** component for that and to find the OS you can make use of the **Platform** component , both available in the react-native library ,

```js
<KeyboardAvoidingView
  behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : undefined}
  keyboardVerticalOffset={-500} // Adjust this value as needed
  style={{ flex: 1 }}
>
  {/* Your screen's content goes here */}
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

Comment: thanks but this is not what i meant, i have updated my question with a photo for better understanding :)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to disable the autocomplete option.
Based on the documentation of React Native V0.71
[React Native - TextInput Docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput)

You can try to disable the autocorrect and select as none the content type of the text. Like the following example code.

```
<TextInput textContentType="none" autoCorrect={false} />
```

I hope it is the answer to your problem.

Comment: Hi pabloguzman, thanks but this is not autoCorrect, this is IOS specific and i don't know what is the proper naming of this addon, but after setting autocorrect to false it still appears.